# Grouping ID and then sum remaining values (SQL / Query)

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am creating a database where clients can buy materials but they are free to pay whenever they want (weekly, for instance). I would like to know if there is a way to display a table with every client (no duplicates) showing how much he/she bought, how much he/she owes and how much he/she has paid.

I have three tables:

- Clients (client info)
- Payments (every time someone pays it gets
  registered)
- OrdersInventory (what was purchased and each item price)

```
Clients    | Payments      | OrdersInventory | 
-----------| --------------|-----------------|
           | PaymentsID    | ItemID          |
ClientsID >|>ClientID      | Qty             |
           | PaymentAmount | NewPrice        |
           | OrderID      >|>OrderID         |
```

The problem occurs when I try to select the data that I need. In this case, there are 2 payments made by one person (PaymentID 3 = $10, and ID 4 = $30) but it is displaying two times the first payment because it is reading two OrderIDs from OrderInventory (in other words, the order contains two items) and `NewPrice*Qty` is the total price for each item (Header name: TotalItemsPrice).

```
ClientID | PaymentID | PaymentAmount | TotalItemsPrice
   1     |     3     |       $10     |    10
   1     |     3     |       $10     |    15
   1     |     4     |       $30     |    30
```

If I sum TotalItemsPrice, I get a good result:

```
ClientID | PaymentID | PaymentAmount | TotalItemsPrice
   1     |     3     |       $10     |    25
   1     |     4     |       $30     |    30
```

Then I got rid of the PaymentID so that later it shows one time ClientID (no duplicates).

```
ClientID | PaymentAmount | TotalItemsPrice
   1     |       $10     |    25
   1     |       $30     |    30
```

Finally, I summed PaymentAmount with the hope of showing only those two values summed ($10+$30 = $40), but instead it get $50 because of the same issue that it is showing it two times the payment when accessing data from OrderInventory.

Result:

```
    ClientID | SumOfPaymentAmount | TotalItemsPrice
       1     |       $50          |    $55
```

Expected result:

```
    ClientID | SumOfPaymentAmount | TotalItemsPrice
       1     |       $40          |    $55
```

I can't manage to do it properly. Could anyone maybe write a solution? I appreciate all help!

This is the final code:

```
SELECT Clients.ClientID, Sum(Payments.PaymentAmount) AS SumOfPaymentAmount, Sum([NewPrice]*[Qty]) AS TotalItemsPrice
FROM Clients RIGHT JOIN (Payments INNER JOIN OrdersInventory ON Payments.OrderID = OrdersInventory.OrderID) ON Clients.ClientID = Payments.ClientID
GROUP BY Clients.ClientID;
```

Comment: Please share your simple data as text not images so it can be easy to help

Comment: Understood. Changed it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see you've tagged both `SQL` and `MS-ACCESS`, depending on what `DBMS` you're using, one solution would be to use `OUTER APPLY` to aggregate your `OrdersInventory` table before the `JOIN`.

```
SELECT c.ClientID
      ,SUM(p.PaymentAmount) AS SumOfPaymentAmount
      ,SUM(oi.TotalItemsPrice) AS TotalItemsPrice
FROM Clients c
LEFT JOIN Payments p ON p.ClientID = c.ClientID
OUTER APPLY (SELECT SUM(Qty * NewPrice) AS TotalItemsPrice
             FROM OrdersInventory
             WHERE OrderID = p.OrderID) oi
GROUP BY c.ClientID
```

If `OUTER APPLY` isn't available, you can do essentially the same thing with `LEFT JOIN`.

```
SELECT c.ClientID
      ,SUM(p.PaymentAmount) AS SumOfPaymentAmount
      ,SUM(oi.TotalItemsPrice) AS TotalItemsPrice
FROM Clients c
LEFT JOIN Payments p ON p.ClientID = c.ClientID
LEFT JOIN (SELECT OrderID
                 ,SUM(Qty * NewPrice) AS TotalItemsPrice
           FROM OrdersInventory
           GROUP BY OrderID) oi ON oi.OrderID = p.OrderID
GROUP BY c.ClientID
```

Comment: This worked. I had a syntax error which was only to have some parenthesis from `Clients.ID` (right after `FROM`) until `c.ClientID` (just before the second `LEFT JOIN`). Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Arturo additional parentheses shouldn't be needed, maybe you're just mixing up the aliases?